# How can i get only the numbers after the decimal in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

I'm trying to not surpass 1 in this double,
it goes `0.1`, `0.2`, `0.3` ....... and then when it reaches `1.1` I want it to go back to `0.1`
so I figured if I can get only the number after the decimal I can add the 0 manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract the int digit.

```dart
double myNum = 1.3;
double decimalPoint = myNum - myNum.toInt();
print(decimalPoint);
```

Comment: Also try checking `.toStringAsPrecision()` and `.toStringAsFixed()`

Comment: Glad to help, Also check the duplicate question link, You will find more.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourDouble = 1.1;
var fixedDouble = yourDouble - yourDouble.floor();
print(fixedDouble); //Output: 0.1
```